# TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument: 'search_query'

Tags: python, django

почему не выполняется метод `get_related_filter` в классе `Money`? выдает ошибку `TypeError: get_related_filter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'search_query'`

**views**

```
modelPath = 'Money.models'
app_model = importlib.import_module(modelPath)
cls = getattr(app_model, 'Money')
related_result = cls.get_related_filter(search_query)
```

**models**

```
class Money(models.Model):
    money = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, blank=True, default=0, decimal_places=2)
    prepayment = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, blank=True, default=0, decimal_places=2)    

    def get_related_filter(sefl, search_query):
        results = super(Money, self).objects.filter(Q(money__icontains=search_query))
        return results

    def __str__(self):
        return self.money
```

Comment: Такое ощущение, что обращение идёт к методу класса, а не к методу объекта этого класса. Кстати, у вас там ещё и опечатка с `sefl`.

Comment: Ответ в выдаваемой ошибке. Отсутствует обязательный аргумент `search_query`. И еще, как написали выше, опечатка в переопределении функции `sefl ---> self`

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы написали **sefl**, а надо `self`
2. Ну и сама ошибка: в методе `get_related_filter` передавать `search_query` не надо. Чтобы использовать `search_query`  вам надо обратится к self:

`results = super(Money, self).objects.filter(Q(money__icontains=self.search_query))`

Если первый способ не сработает, можно сделать через kwargs, то есть в ваш метод `get_related_filter` вторым аргументом передать **kwargs** и указать в нём `search_query`:

```
def get_related_filter(self, kwargs):
    results = super(Money, self).objects.filter(Q(money__icontains=self.kwargs["search_query"]))
    return results
```